# Why Unity Cient doesn't call the server command?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, command

Wen I press the send button (so call the Send function) the client doesn't call the server command. The server call the RPC function well and send the message and the client show it as I expected.
Local Player Authority is checked.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[System.Obsolete]
public class chat : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public GameObject input;
    public Transform content;
    public GameObject messageobj;
    private Text text;

    private void Start()
    {
        text = input.GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    public void Send()
    {
        Debug.Log("Send");
        CmdSend(text.text);
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdSend(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("CMD");
        RpcSend(message);
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    public void RpcSend(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("RPC");
        PutMessageToScreen(message);
    }

    public void PutMessageToScreen(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("all");
        GameObject mess = Instantiate(messageobj, content);
        mess.GetComponent<Text>().text = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: looking at your code, it looks like the flow is: client sends command to server, server responds with rpc to client, client displays message. if you're saying the RPC was received, it means the command was received as well

Comment: The command only recived if the host (the server) called it.

Comment: Commands are sent from clients to server. RPCs are sent from server to clients. If the player object has authority and sends the command it should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object which has this scrip was on the scene. Not the manager spawned it and this is why it didn't sent the command.
The chat must be attached to the player!